# Images in Velocity Word Template

Tags: templates, velocity, vtl

I'm trying to pull images from a platform working with tables. Within the platform, there are document automation capabilities based on vlt. The VTL code is written within a word file that is then uploaded to the platform.

I'm trying to pull images from that platform into my automated word document. If the image is stored as an URL, the doc auto only pulls the URL. When the image is stored as an attachment or file link within the platform, I do not get an output at all.

This is what my word template looks like:

```
#set($isheet ='Document Automation Test')
#set($viewName='Export')
#set($columns={})
#set($FNum = "")
$!{columns.put("imgAtt","Image as attachment")}
#set($data=$utils.getSheetDocReportDataMap($isheet,$viewName,$columns))
#foreach($record in $data)

$record.imgAtt

#end
```

This is not working. Is there a way to get VTL to download the image first and then embed it into the document?

Comment: Related: https://community.liferay.com/forums/-/message_boards/message/56841164

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot insert images into word via html.